# touchesMoved out of the self view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gesture, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I'm working on an important project at my job place, and having a problem which I'm stack with:

I have 2 views in a line (1 scroll view with images, and the other is just a `UIImageView`), I would like to make it able to move an image from the scroll view into the `UIImageView`), I could successfully recognize and move the image from the scrollView, but the problem is when the movement goes out of the scrollView the image dropped disappears behind and could not reach the road to the imageView.

any suggestions please?

Comment: do you want to drag image from `scrollView`, and drop it into `imageView` ?

Comment: Yeap, exactly, this is what I'm trying to do. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I've been searching the wen for two days and found no solution, thought it is silly not let developers do such a thing... I really hope I'm wrong!

Comment: Are you using an iPad with UISplitScreenController?

Comment: No, just a UIViewController as a master view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of a UIView and display the image on this view. Then implement the methods touchesDidBegin, touchesMoved, touchesCancelled on this subclass. Use this new UIView in your scrollview for the images you want to drag, and make sure the scrollview.clipsToBounds = NO.

In touchesMoved, adjust the position of the view's frame and when touchesEnd, get the position of the frame to determine if it's in the other view.